# Simply this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry. I feel dumb for not remembering how to do this but I'm helping my girlfriend with some math stuff and I'm forgetting how to simplify this expression.

$$\sqrt 3 - 27$$

I think that you are suppose to multiply or divide it by something so we can get rid of the sqrt but I'm stumped on how to accomplish that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing left to do to simplify the expression any further.

Comment: expression in form as it is is enough simple

Comment: Wow, her professor is a troll then. Thank you guys.

Comment: And this question has got an upvote! I DON'T KNOW what has become of the people here!

Comment: There isn't much to simplify in that expression. Of course $\sqrt{3}-27$ $=\sqrt{3}(1-9\sqrt{3})$ $=\sqrt{3}\frac{1-9^2\cdot3}{1+9\sqrt{3}}$ but neither is a *simplification* unless there is some more context to it.

Comment: If you had something like $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{3}-27}$, you might rationalize the denominator by multiplying top-and-bottom by the conjugate $\sqrt{3}+27$. However, the expression $\sqrt{3}-27$ alone is fine.

Comment: @Qwerty It's an honest question asked in good faith, with a specific problem and an attempt at solving it. Why should it not have an upvote?

Comment: @PatrickStevens When I hover my mose over the upvote sign , it says **shows _research effort_ , and is _useful_**. Does this question really satisfy these two?

Comment: Any chance that you've misspelled your girlfriend's question from $\sqrt[3]{-27}$ into $\sqrt{3}-27$?

Answer (score 1):

Many people already pointed out that your expression can't really get much more neater than that. One can, however, do the following:

$$27 = 3^3 \Rightarrow 27 = {\sqrt 3}^6,\\
\sqrt 3 - 27 = \sqrt 3 - {\sqrt 3}^6 = \sqrt 3 (1 - {\sqrt 3}^5) = \sqrt 3 (1 - 9\sqrt 3)$$

Comment: This answer stretches the definition of 'simplify' a little.

Comment: @user259242 sure it does, but apart from this, and assuming we **must** do something, everything else will be more complicated than this.